# How to insert data in SQLite table after process completion in php?

Tags: javascript, php, database, sqlite, websocket

I have a **table** setup in **SQLite database** in which there are **2 columns** and **2 records**. Records are **list of mp4 files** from the directory.

[image]

I also have a php code in which I am **scanning list of mp4 files**  from a directory. Any new mp4 file which comes inside a directory goes inside the **Podcast_Export table** above.

> Status.php

```
<?php
  $mp4_files = array_values($mp4_files);

  print_r($mp4_files);  // Line X

  foreach ($programs as $key => $program) { 
       $file = $mp4_files[$key];   

       print_r($file);   // Line Y   
       print_r($key);    // Line Z

?>  

<tr class="box" data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
<td>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" 
         class="btn btn-outline-primary">
  </input></td>  // Line D
</tr>
```

**Line X** prints `Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )` 
**Line Y** prints `36031P.mp4 hello.mp4`  
**Line Z** prints `0 and 1`

On click `Go` button at Line D, the following JS/jQuery code is called.

> JS/jQuery

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($)
   {
    $('.converter').click(function()
    {   
        let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');
        let btn = this;
        $(btn).val("Converting").prop('disabled', true);   // Line A
        $.ajax({
            url: 'convert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: target}, 
            success: function(res)
            {
                 $(btn).val("Completed").prop('disabled', true);  // Line B
            },
        })
    })
   });
```

=> **Line A** change button text from **Go** to **Converting** (meaning conversion is in process). 
=> **Line B** tells that the conversion is Completed (and the **Converting** text gets change to **Completed**).

**Problem Statement:**

The HTML code (UI) from where the jQuery code is called:

```
<td><button data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="converter btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button></td>
```

Comment: store the state in some kind of datastore.

Comment: HTTP is stateless -- when you refresh the page, the page doesn't know that you're the same person who just submitted a job. One way (perhaps) to implement this is store a cookie on the client. When they visit the page, check to see if there are any active / in progress jobs associated with that cookie, and update the UI accordingly. But this will not work if you open the webpage on different machines (unless you have a concept of an "account" and tie the in-progress job to all users on that account).

Comment: ^ in HTTP this would be a session, probably leveraging cookies and a 'datastore' like your file system or better yet a database.

Comment: Or use WebSockets

Comment: Yes webockets is the another way. I am wondering how we can use it.

Comment: @DanielA.White I will edit the question to avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @ficuscr I have setup the database with `House_number` and `Status` column. House number corresponds to mp4 files in the directory (lets say src_directory). Let me know how I can use the database to solve my problem statement.

Comment: Could you be more specific what exactly the problem is? The title says "How to insert data in SQLite table after process completion in php?" but your problem stated later-on refers to HTML code. If you only want to store data inside your sqlite database, simply save the file to DB as soon as the `convert.php` succeeds, as part of the script. BTW, `<input>` is a so-called void element that never has content so it has no closing tag. It should be `<input type="submit" value="Go">`.

Comment: can you please mention `convert.php` code so that we can help you to sort this problem.

Comment: I think this why we have services and sessions concepts. If you want something to be user specifically displayed across multiple interfaces, his state must be stored in server not in UI. Websockets or XHR I dont think that makes a difference.

Comment: - Use `var` in place of `let` because it only works on modern browsers.
- Change the Go button to `<button type='button' class="converter">GO</button>`
You have two option to resolve what you are looking for:
1. You can update the table right from the `convert.php`. Recommended
2. Make another ajax call inside the ajax's success callback.

Answer (score 0):

(the question is not really clear at the moment since much content was removed in revision 17. So my answer refers to some content of [revision 16](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56602382/16))

1. Make your `status.php` script to select the `Status` from `Podcast_Export` as well.
   So that **Line X** prints (for example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [House_number] => 36031P.mp4
            [Status] => Go
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [House_number] => hello.mp4
            [Status] => Completed
        )
)
```

2. Edit the button to reflect the current state:

```php
<?php
$state = $mp4_files[$key]['Status'];
$buttonDisabled = ($state == "Converting" || $state == "Completed") ? "disabled" : "";
?>
<input type="submit"
       value="<?php echo $state; ?>"
       data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" 
       class="btn btn-outline-primary"
       <?php echo $buttonDisabled; ?>>
```

3. At the beginning of your `convert.php` script, perform an `UPDATE` to the `Podcast_Export` table that sets the `Status` to `Converting`.
   Do the same at the end of that script (where the conversion is completed) but this time set the `Status` to `Completed`.